# Will installing Arch stop my laptop getting stuck on boot screen?

Tags: linux, hardware, archlinux

Despite having it's hard drive, motherboard, and various components replaced repeatedly (due to unrelated damages and insurance) my laptop often gets stuck on the boot screen, that is, a backlit black screen with a flashing white cursor.

The cursor will often stop flashing, meaning the laptop has to be turned back off and on again and again until it makes it to the TOSHIBA logo.
As the laptop is now not worth very much, is it worth completely replacing the Windows7 OS and installing Arch?

Will this have any effect at all on my frozen boot screen problem?

Comment: Test it by using a live CD / live USB Linux distro. No need to install, just run the OS from the USB stick. That's a good way to check if it is a hardware problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is happening in the boot/bios - installing a new OS won't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be sorted out if you understand this sequence.

First make sure RAM, GPU and Screen are OK and laptop is clean inside.

**1. BIOS:** When you turn computer ON, it checks for BIOS first. It's small program that resides on a chip on motherboard. If you can enter into BIOS by pressing ESC, F2, F12 or DEL key (your computer may have a different key) every time you turn it on, then the problem isn't with BIOS. If the problem is with BIOS, flash it.

**2. Bootloader:** is a small software that resides on hard drive at a fixed location called Boot Sector of hard drive. BIOS will try to load bootloader. If boot sector is corrupt then you won't proceed next. You might have to partition and format your hard drive for a clean install.

**3. Operating System** Bootloader then loads operating system (Linux, Windows, Mac OS or whatever). If it does not load or loads extremely slow, chances are there are bad sectors on hard drive.

Most of the problems arise from dust inside computers. So you must open it clean properly. Open the computer clean detach detachable components and re-seat them.

The problem may also arise from expired thermal paste that connects microprocessor with heat sink. This paste is usually changed after 3-4 years. Monitor the temperature of CPU and if it is high than 90 degrees then change thermal paste.

The problem may be due to dead CMOS battery causing BIOS to loose its saved values every time. Change CMOS battery in this case.

Every OS has its own load on computer resources (mainly processor and RAM)  . Hence every manufacturer recommends a particular operating system for each model of his machine. For example, running Windows 7 on Acer Aspire One designed for Windows XP would soon bring trouble to your netbook. Why? It is because Windows 7 may keep your netbook heated up all the time resulting in failure of one or more components. Choose the right OS for the machine. Always read the requirements that must be fulfilled before you install an OS.